# zend engine return object reference

Tags: php, c, php-internals

In php, it is valid to write something like this:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

How can I do this inside zend engine? I want a method to execute some operations, then return the class instance reference.

Furthermore, I would like to store some objects (from other classes) and return them as result of some other methods, should i store it's `zval*`? What is the right way to return a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you need to return the `zval*`. You need to use `RETURN_ZVAL` for this, which is declared as:

```
RETURN_ZVAL(zv, ctor, dtor)
```

The first argument, `zv` is your `zval*`. The second `ctor` tells the Zend Engine to use the copy constructor (it's for maintaining the `refcount`). The last argument, `dtor` tells the Zend Engine to apply the destructor to `zv` (related to the `refcount` too). Typically, unless you know what you are doing, these last two arguments should be `1` and `0` respectively.

To return `$this`, per example:

```
PHP_METHOD(Foo, bar)
{
     RETURN_ZVAL(getThis(), 1, 0);
}
```

Here, `getThis()` returns a `zval*` to `$this`. You can pass any other `zval*` containing a PHP object if you want to.